# jQuery nth-child not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

I am trying trying to use jQuery to add margins on every 3rd `section` element in the parent:

```
$(function(){
    $('.portfolio-box:nth-child(3n)').css("margin", "0px 0 30px 0");
});
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<section class="portfolio-contents">
<section class="portfolio-box"></section>
<section class="portfolio-box"></section>
<section class="portfolio-box"></section>
</section>
```

This is all working on all browsers including IE8 and above, but its not working on IE7 please help.

This works fine with every browser except Internet Explorer 7. Anyone know why/how I can fix it?

Comment: How are you testing? IETester by any chance?

Comment: Please describe "not working". When you are trying to explain a problem, "not working" is NEVER enough.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the [html5 shim](http://code.google.com/p/html5shim/)? Worst case scenario, use divs instead of sections. They seem to work under ie7: http://jsfiddle.net/Dsmns/